# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1/2$ by definition

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Suppose that
$$
a_n=\frac{n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+4n-1}.
$$
I am trying to show that for each positive number $\epsilon$, there is a number $N$ such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$.

**Attempt**

Clearly $L=1/2$ as $n\to\infty$. So,
\begin{align}
|a_n-L|&=\left|\frac{n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+4n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{-4n+3/2}{2n^2+4n-1}\right| \\
&\leq \left|\frac{-4n+3/2}{4n-1}\right| \\
&\leq \frac{4n}{4n-1}+\frac{3/2}{4n-1} \\
&= \frac{4n-1}{4n-1}+\frac{5/2}{4n-1} \\ 
&= 1+\frac{5/2}{4n-1}. \\ 
\end{align}
We require
$$
1+\frac{5/2}{4n-1}<\epsilon\implies n>\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{5}{2(\epsilon-1)}+1\right)=N.
$$

Note that I have made the assumption that $n>0$ since we are considering $n\to\infty$. Is this logic correct? Have I made any mistakes or assumptions?

Comment: for $\epsilon < 1$, it won't work. You should't remove $n^2$ in first $\le$ sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the fisrt inequality step,

Since $2n^2+4n-1 \ge n^2$ and $\left|-4n+3/2\right| \le 4n$,
\begin{align}
|a_n-L|&=\left|\frac{n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+4n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{-4n+3/2}{2n^2+4n-1}\right| \\
&\leq \left|\frac{4n}{n^2}\right| \\
&=\frac{4}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you went from the second line to the third line?

Comment: Does $|-4n+3/2|\leq 4n$ follow from the triangle inequality?

Comment: you can the inequlity part into comparing the inequlity of two numerators and denominators, there are a lot of ways to compare these, just pick one you think it is suitable.

Comment: No, $|-4n+3/2|=4n-3/2\leq 4n$

Comment: I'm confused. Since $|-4n+3/2|=|4n-3/2|$, how can you drop the absolute values and claim that $|4n-3/2|=4n-3/2$? Are you assuming $n$ is sufficiently large and therefore the expression is positive?

Comment: @Bell  n is always $\ge 1$, so you can drop this

Comment: I see. Silly question, but why is this?

Comment: Since $4n-3/2$ is positive,  you can remove the absolute sign

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
|a_n-L|&=\left|\frac{n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+4n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{-4n+3/2}{2n^2+4n-1}\right| \\
&\leq\frac{4n+3/2}{2n^2+4n-1} \\
&\leq \frac{8n}{2n^2}=\dfrac4n \\
\end{align}
We require
$$\dfrac4n<\epsilon\iff n>\frac4{\epsilon}\,.$$

Consequently,

for any $\,\epsilon>0\,$ there exists $\,N=\max\left\{\left\lfloor\dfrac4{\epsilon}\right\rfloor,1\right\}\in\Bbb N\,$ such that $\;|a_n-L|<\epsilon\;\;$ whenever $\,n>N\,.\\\\$

---

**Addendum :**

$n>N\implies n>\dfrac4{\epsilon}\,.$

Indeed, if $\,n>N=\max\left\{\left\lfloor\dfrac4{\epsilon}\right\rfloor,1\right\}\,,\,$ then $\,n>\left\lfloor\dfrac4{\epsilon}\right\rfloor\,,\,$ hence, $\,n\geq\left\lfloor\dfrac4{\epsilon}\right\rfloor+1>\dfrac4{\epsilon}\,.$

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with $ \epsilon -1$ as it can easily be negative if $\epsilon < 1$. So, your inequality for n is false. It's true if $\epsilon - 1 > 0$. The problem is that you deleted $2n^2$ and the inequality is weak and can't prove the theorem, because clearly $|\frac{-4n + \frac{3}{2}}{4n-1}|$ approaches 1, not $0$. As a hint, in that very step divide the numerator and the denominator  by $n^2$, and use Archimedean property of real numbers: $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \ n_0 \in N$ such that $ \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ when $ n > n_0$.